# Require Composer v2.0?

Tags: package, composer-php

Is there a way to require someone to have composer v2.0 installed, so that otherwise a project can't be build, when running "composer install"? I just find version requirements related to specific composer packages, but no way to require a certain version for composer itself, but maybe someone knows more about it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `composer require composer-runtime-api:^2`